# Considering attempting a canonical question on kickstands

Tags: discussion

We have a [[kickstand] tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kickstand) with a reasonable amount of use.  Depsite an old, generic question [Which kickstand to choose?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/34973/7309) we don't really have anything to point other questions at (e.g. [How to select double leg kickstand](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/30697/7309), [Where should I install the kickstand?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/29342/7309) Batman's answer to which addresses *some* points very nicely).

I think we could do with a *"What are the various types of kickstands and their pros and cons?"* I could write the question and *some* answers if that seemed helpful.

I considered whether a major expansion of the tag wiki would be a better approach, but it would end up being pretty long (taking into account the need for images).

---

The full text of the tag wiki is:

> A kickstand is a device on a bicycle or motorcycle that allows the bike to be kept upright without leaning against another object or the aid of a person. A kickstand is usually a piece of metal that flips down from the frame and makes contact with the ground. It is generally located in the middle of the bike or towards the rear. Some touring bikes have two: one at the rear, and a second in the front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get round to doing it before my holiday. While I was away we had a question with a nice generic title, for which [RoboKaren wrote a comprehensive answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/47824/7309) so we no longer need the question I proposed.

Comment: Answered mainly as a hook to hang the link on.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, sure, why not? I'm a fan of canonical questions for things like this.